# Not able to install Microsoft Build Tools 2013 on Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 1

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-installation, build

I am kind of stuck on this. 
I have installed .NET 4.5.2 and Winver tool shows this information:
Windows Server 2008 R2
Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service pack 1)

I have ran a Windows update also.

When I click INSTALL on the installer it is just stuck there. Refuses to move.
Also I see some errors on the welcome page of the installer:

```
Setup requires 17MB on C: and 65MB on C:
```

Any pointers?

EDIT: 
I got the Build Tools 2013 from this link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40760

Regards

Comment: Should I move this to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real reason was that I did not install .NET Framework 4.5 Software Development Kit. After installing [Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx), it went fine.

<strike>This is weird but somehow worked.
I did a command line install and provided a custom path for install.
Install succeeded. But it did not install in the folder location I specified. Instead the software was installed in the default location. Place where it would have had got installed if done without specifying the custom path.</strike>